# Color of text of paragraph doesn't works in Firexfox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a paragraph on my page:

```
<p class='errorMessage'></p>
```

It has css property

```
.errorMessage
{
    color: red;
}
```

That works fine in chrome and safari but text is still black in IE and Firefox. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We're going to need more than that to be able to help as I doubt this on its own fails! There must be other CSS at play which create a conflict somewhere. In general the more you post about your error the easier it is to get help :)

Comment: You can right click on the <p> element and Inspect Element to find out why it not work.

Comment: Well I use twitter bootstrap. May be in's styles override my. Trying to fix in in firefox now.

Comment: just set full path at css (div#id div .class p.errorMessage)and it works fine at firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
.errorMessage{
     color:red !important;
}
```

If this works, another css style overrides your rule. Otherwise there must be something wrong with the document (i.e. incorrect style tags,...).

Comment: This works in IE but firefox is still works wrong=).